# Как проще заменить текст ссылки при наведении?

Tags: html, css, текст, hover, display

```css
#knpgh_a {
 display: block;
 width: 90%;
 height: 30px;
 margin-left: 8%;
 font-size: 16px;
 z-index: 9;
}
#knpgh_a2 {
 display: none;
 width: 86%;
 height: 30px;
 margin-left: 8%;
 font-size: 16px;
 margin-top: -30px;
}
.knpgh_a {
 color: black;
 text-decoration: none;
}
#knpgh_a:hover + #knpgh_a2{
 display: block;
 color: #415C7F;
}
#knpgh_a:hover {
 color: rgba(0,0,0,0.0);
}
```

```html
<a href="" class="knpgh_a">
  <p id="knpgh_a">Североамериканское</p>
  <p id="knpgh_a2">Североамериканское кино</p>
</a>
```

Какими еще способами посоветуете воспользоваться для корректного отображения заменяемого текста? В примере выше - он моргает как бешенная пота*куха. 
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Моргание доставило, забавный баг.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Всё гораздо проще:

```css
a:hover .a {
  display: none;
}
a .b {
  display: none;
}
a:hover .b {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <span class="a">text 1</span>
  <span class="b">text 2</span>
</a>
```

Comment: Прибольшущая благодарность!